# Custom field for default gallery

Tags: custom-field, shortcode, gallery

How I can add custom field in default WordPress gallery? in visual editor and in shortcode.

[image]

Comment: Check plugin Media Library Custom Fields: http://wordpress.org/plugins/media-library-custom-fields/

Comment: It's only for images(attachments).
For this we can use filters **attachment_fields_to_edit** and **attachment_fields_to_save**.