# Add custom fields to wp native gallery settings

Tags: custom-field, gallery

i already searched for solution and found a lot of unsolved or obsolete topics.

[Custom wordpress gallery option](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/179357/custom-wordpress-gallery-option/182818#182818)
| [Custom field for default gallery](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/100491/custom-field-for-default-gallery)

However, I´d like to add some custom fields (checkboxes, cyclebuttons etc.) to add attributes to the gallery shortcut. Does anyone have some snippes?

---

EDIT: Finally Ive found this https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-add-fields-to-gallery-settings and its doing all I want it to do. :)rownn

---

EDIT:
Based on upper link I wrote following lines.

```
add_action('print_media_templates', function(){
?>
<script type="text/html" id="tmpl-custom-gallery-setting">
    <h3 style="z-index: -1;">___________________________________________________________________________________________</h3>
    <h3>Custom Settings</h3>

    <label class="setting">
        <span><?php _e('Text'); ?></span>
        <input type="text" value="" data-setting="ds_text" style="float:left;">
    </label>

    <label class="setting">
        <span><?php _e('Textarea'); ?></span>
        <textarea value="" data-setting="ds_textarea" style="float:left;"></textarea>
    </label>

    <label class="setting">
        <span><?php _e('Number'); ?></span>
        <input type="number" value="" data-setting="ds_number" style="float:left;" min="1" max="9">
    </label>

    <label class="setting">
      <span><?php _e('Select'); ?></span>
      <select data-setting="ds_select">
        <option value="option1"> 'Option-1' </option>
        <option value="option2"> 'Option-2' </option>
      </select>
    </label>

    <label class="setting">
        <span><?php _e('Bool'); ?></span>
        <input type="checkbox" data-setting="ds_bool">
    </label>

</script>

<script>

    jQuery(document).ready(function()
    {
        _.extend(wp.media.gallery.defaults, {
        ds_text: 'no text',
        ds_textarea: 'no more text',
        ds_number: "3",
        ds_select: 'option1',
        ds_bool: false,
        ds_text1: 'dummdideldei'
        });

        wp.media.view.Settings.Gallery = wp.media.view.Settings.Gallery.extend({
        template: function(view){
          return wp.media.template('gallery-settings')(view)
               + wp.media.template('custom-gallery-setting')(view);
        }
        });

    });

</script>
<?php

});
```

[image: ui]
UserInterface
[image: shortcode]
Shortcode

Everthings works fine beside: The number field isnt filled by shortcode. I believe the reason for this is that the HTML-input-tag type "number" only accept integer for "value". What do I have to add to code to change the string of ds_number to int?

Greetings
rownn

Comment: Please post your code, working or not.

Comment: Im caught! I have no code. I know its a thick way to ask for snippes, but I have no idea. :/ I wanted to analyse a working code to see how it works. I know Ive to manage it with add_action() for adding and saving, but I dont know how create certain types at certain places.

Comment: @rownn, you should post your code as an answer rather than editing the question - then accept it: :)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your code. I've investigated this issue further (this is not an integer formatting problem). The only solution I came up with for number fields is to monkey patch more WP JS. Here is entire code with modifications which supports any input type:

```
add_action('print_media_templates', function(){
?>
<script type="text/html" id="tmpl-custom-gallery-setting">
    <h3>Custom Settings</h3>

    <label class="setting">
        <span><?php _e('Text'); ?></span>
        <input type="text" value="" data-setting="ds_text" style="float:left;">
    </label>

    <label class="setting">
        <span><?php _e('Textarea'); ?></span>
        <textarea value="" data-setting="ds_textarea" style="float:left;"></textarea>
    </label>

    <label class="setting">
        <span><?php _e('Number'); ?></span>
        <input type="number" value="" data-setting="ds_number" style="float:left;" min="1" max="9">
    </label>

    <label class="setting">
      <span><?php _e('Select'); ?></span>
      <select data-setting="ds_select">
        <option value="option1"> 'Option-1' </option>
        <option value="option2"> 'Option-2' </option>
      </select>
    </label>

    <label class="setting">
        <span><?php _e('Bool'); ?></span>
        <input type="checkbox" data-setting="ds_bool">
    </label>

</script>

<script>

    jQuery(document).ready(function()
    {
        _.extend(wp.media.gallery.defaults, {
        ds_text: 'no text',
        ds_textarea: 'no more text',
        ds_number: "3",
        ds_select: 'option1',
        ds_bool: false,
        ds_text1: 'dummdideldei'
        });

        wp.media.view.Settings.Gallery = wp.media.view.Settings.Gallery.extend({
        template: function(view){
          return wp.media.template('gallery-settings')(view)
               + wp.media.template('custom-gallery-setting')(view);
        },
        // this is function copies from WP core /wp-includes/js/media-views.js?ver=4.6.1
        update: function( key ) {
          var value = this.model.get( key ),
            $setting = this.$('[data-setting="' + key + '"]'),
            $buttons, $value;

          // Bail if we didn't find a matching setting.
          if ( ! $setting.length ) {
            return;
          }

          // Attempt to determine how the setting is rendered and update
          // the selected value.

          // Handle dropdowns.
          if ( $setting.is('select') ) {
            $value = $setting.find('[value="' + value + '"]');

            if ( $value.length ) {
              $setting.find('option').prop( 'selected', false );
              $value.prop( 'selected', true );
            } else {
              // If we can't find the desired value, record what *is* selected.
              this.model.set( key, $setting.find(':selected').val() );
            }

          // Handle button groups.
          } else if ( $setting.hasClass('button-group') ) {
            $buttons = $setting.find('button').removeClass('active');
            $buttons.filter( '[value="' + value + '"]' ).addClass('active');

          // Handle text inputs and textareas.
          } else if ( $setting.is('input[type="text"], textarea') ) {
            if ( ! $setting.is(':focus') ) {
              $setting.val( value );
            }
          // Handle checkboxes.
          } else if ( $setting.is('input[type="checkbox"]') ) {
            $setting.prop( 'checked', !! value && 'false' !== value );
          }
          // HERE the only modification I made
          else {
            $setting.val( value ); // treat any other input type same as text inputs
          }
          // end of that modification
        },
        });
    });

</script>
<?php
```

Comment: looks like "wp.media.gallery.defaults" is now "wp.media.galleryDefaults"

Comment: thanks everyone, this came very handy :)